# trying to do calculation of 2 input fields update in real-time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate 2 input fields and display the result  in real-time in div totalPrice
no matter what I've tried can't get it to work

thx

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
    jQuery('#field2').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
        var op1 = document.getElementById('field1');
        var op2 = document.getElementById('field2');
        var result = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
        if (op1.value == "" || op1.value != parseFloat(op1.value)) op1.value = 0;
        if (op2.value == "" || op2.value != parseFloat(op2.value)) op2.value = 0;
        result.value = 0;
        result.value = parseInt(result.value);
        result.value = parseInt(result.value) + parseInt(op1.value) + parseInt(op2.value);
    }
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice'); divobj.style.display = 'block'; divobj.innerHTML = "Total $" + result.value;
    });
</script>
<form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" value="" size="20" name="field1" id="field1" class="rsform-input-box">
    <input type="text" value="" size="20" name="field2" id="field2" class="rsform-input-box">
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: There's an extra `}` above `var divobj`.

Comment: what is `op1.value!=parseFloat(op1.value)` this condition for?

Comment: not understanding op1.value != parseFloat(op1.value) this condition????

Comment: Also, put the script after the html form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this http://jsfiddle.net/20Lgz8ey/2/

```
 $('#field1,#field2').on('input propertychange paste', function() {


     $('#totalPrice').html(parseFloat($("#field1").val()!=''?$("#field1").val():0)+parseFloat($("#field2").val()!=''?$("#field2").val():0));
    });
```

also

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   code ....
</script>
```

Comment: Or `$('.rsform-input-box'.on(...)`

Comment: selecting by id is fastest so I used that as after finding a object with id selector stops searching but in case of class it will parse whole document

Comment: I've used this code but it still won't work for me? I've tried in local file and also hosted file no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#field2, #field1').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
            var op1 = document.getElementById('field1');
            var op2 = document.getElementById('field2');
            var result = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
            if (op1.value == "" || op1.value != parseFloat(op1.value)) op1.value = 0;
            if (op2.value == "" || op2.value != parseFloat(op2.value)) op2.value = 0;
            result.value = 0;
            result.value = parseInt(result.value);
            result.value = parseInt(result.value) + parseInt(op1.value) + parseInt(op2.value);
            var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice'); divobj.style.display = 'block'; divobj.innerHTML = "Total $" + result.value;
        })            
    });
```

try this if it helps you.